# Dynamic route and additional search params in url in NextJS

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

I'm trying to redirect a user with `router.push(url);` where an url is like the following: `[:lang]/something/[...dynamicRouteParams]?searchParam=true`.

There's an issue, that a user is redirected to a page with URL: `[:lang]/something/[...dynamicRouteParams]?searchParam=true&lang=something&dynamicRouteParams=item1&dynamicRouteParams=item2`.

How can I get rid of the search params related to route params?

Comment: it's not possible to do that because getStatciProps runs on build time and it doesn't contain query.  use getServerSideProps for that case

Comment: I'm using `getServerSideProps` and inside it the url already contains unwanted parts. Why did you assume I'm using `getStaticProps`? There's something in `router.push` method that adds such params to url (after investigating the codebase of nextjs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`

```
export async function getServerSideProps({res, params }) {
  
  //get data you need from API or params
  const data = api or params
  //now redirect to a link with params
  res.setHeader("location", "/URL_WITH_PARAMS");
  // you still need 'return' because of react structure
    return {
      props: {
        data
      },
    }

}
```

Notice: Router.push() only client-side (rendering)

P.S You can pass any params and retrieve it page you land. Check [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)